# Is it possible to find the remaining angles/lengths of this linkage, given only the angle and lengths shown?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a linkage drawn in CAD which represents a "real life" mechanism (a "friction hinge" for a window similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ylZISiVbXA) and I need to solve the positioning mathematically:

[image: Linkage]

'FP' on the drawing is a fixed point, and 'l2' is constrained to be aligned with this fixed point (so this piece slides on a rail which always points exactly to 'FP'). The 'l7' side is a rigid arm (i.e. 'l5' and 'l6 are always co-linear). We know all of the lengths in green/yellow ('l1' to 'l7'), and want to solve length 's1' (in purple) for a given angle 'ad' (currently set at 45°).

Our CAD software manages to solve this shape for a given angle but I need to do it mathematically for reasons I won't go into. I've been able to work it all out if I'm given an angle between the 'l7' side and the 's1' side - I can solve every remaining side and angle but it's a complicated series of steps and I can't work out how to do it in reverse.

It's my suspicion that because the mechanism can be in a few(?) different configurations for a given angle as seen here:

[image: Correct positioning]

(Note 'FP' is at bottom of photo and the sliding part 'l2' is the grey plastic piece towards the middle left of the image)

[image: Incorrect positioning]

then this is why I'm having problems. The mechanism does work though as long as there are certain constraints - all points must go to the same side of the light blue horizontal axis on the drawings, and the sliding part 'l2' cannot be allowed to move too far towards 'FP' otherwise the linkage "collapses" - on the physical mechanism this is achieved by the sliding part being physically limited in its travel by a stop.

Can I calculate what I need to given the constraints above? If so how do I go about it?

(Note: In the photos of the real life mechanism, the length L4 is extended to form a supporting arm but this is not relevant to the maths of the linkage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I assume you care about the case where all parts of the mechanism are only on one side of $B(FP)$. That's the case I am going to address. Then, one can write $\text{ad}$ as a function of $s_1$. The inverse function, i.e. $s_1$ as a function of $\text{ad}$ is implicit.

The key is to calculate the angle $\omega = \angle \, B\,(FP)\,E = \angle \, C\,(FP)\,D$ (the latter equality holds because the points $FP, \, C, \, B$ are collinear and the points $FP, \, D, \, E$ are also collinear), then calculate the length $y$ of $BE$ and with its help find the angles $\theta = \angle \, EB(FP)$ and $\beta = \angle \, BEA$. After that, $\text{ad} = \theta - \beta$.  Observe that $C(FP) = s_1 - l_2$.

**$\text{ad}$ as a function of $s_1$.** By the law of cosines for triangle $C(FP)D$

$$\cos(\omega) = \frac{(s_1 - l_2)^2 + l_6^2 - l_3^2}{2 \, l_6(s_1 - l_2)}$$

By the law of cosines for triangle $B(FP)E$

\begin{align} y^2 &= s_1^2 + l_7^2 - 2 \, l_7 s_1 \cos(\omega) =  s_1^2 + l_7^2 -  l_7 s_1  \frac{(s_1 - l_2)^2 + l_6^2 - l_3^2}{l_6(s_1 - l_2)}\\ 
y^2 &= \frac{l_6(s_1 - l_2)\big( s_1^2 + l_7^2 \big)  - l_7 s_1 \Big( \, (s_1 - l_2)^2 + l_6^2 - l_3^2 \, \Big)}{l_6(s_1 - l_2)}\\
y &=\sqrt{ \, \frac{l_6(s_1 - l_2)\big( s_1^2 + l_7^2 \big)  - l_7 s_1 \Big( \, (s_1 - l_2)^2 + l_6^2 - l_3^2 \, \Big)}{l_6(s_1 - l_2)} \, }
\end{align}

By the law of cosines for triangle $B(FP)E$
$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{y^2 + s_1^2 - l_7^2}{2 \, s_1 y}$$ which means that
$$\theta = \text{arccos}\left( \, \frac{y^2 + s_1^2 - l_7^2}{2 \, s_1 y} \, \right)$$

By the law of cosines for triangle $ABE$
$$\cos(\beta) = \frac{y^2 + l_4^2 - l_1^2}{2 \, l_4 y}$$ which means that
$$\beta = \text{arccos}\left( \, \frac{y^2 + l_4^2 - l_1^2}{2 \, l_4 y} \, \right)$$

Finally, $\text{ad} = \theta - \beta$ so

$$\text{ad} = \text{arccos}\left( \, \frac{y^2 + s_1^2 - l_7^2}{2 \, s_1 y} \, \right) \, - \, \text{arccos}\left( \, \frac{y^2 + l_4^2 - l_1^2}{2 \, l_4 y} \, \right)$$
where 
\begin{align}
y &=\sqrt{ \, \frac{l_6(s_1 - l_2)\big( s_1^2 + l_7^2 \big)  - l_7 s_1 \Big( \, (s_1 - l_2)^2 + l_6^2 - l_3^2 \, \Big)}{l_6(s_1 - l_2)} \, }
\end{align}
The choice of $\cos$ and $\text{arccos}$ and not other trigonometric functions, comes partially from the idea that $\text{arccos}$ captures accurately the angles between $0$ and $\pi$ which is exactly the relevant domain for both $\theta$ and $\beta$.

As you can see, the angle $\text{ad}$ is an explicit function of $s_1$, however, the dependence is quite complicated and doesn't allow for an easy inversion of $s_1$ as a function of $\text{ad}$. Nevertheless, the dependence exists and one can run a simple computer calculation, based only upon the last two formulas, to generate an adequate table of values for $s_1$ and $\text{ad}$. One can even plot the graph of the dependence. Alternatively, one can easily manufacture a fairly accurate numerical method for finding values of $s_1$ given values for $\text{ad}$.

Just a final thought. One algorithm you can run, to find $s_1$ given $\text{ad}$ is the binary dissection of intervals. It goes like this.

Let me denote the function given by the last two equations as $\text{ad} = f(s_1)$ (calculated by a simple computer code). We know that as $s_1$ grows, the angle $\text{ad} = f(s_1)$ decreases monotonically. Determine the interval domain for $s_1$. Let's say $s_1 \in [a,b]$. Calculate the interval $[f(b), f(a)]$ and set an accuracy level $\epsilon$. Then

1. You are given a value $\text{ad} = \alpha_0 \, \in [f(b), f(a)]$. Since the function $f(s_1)$ is continuous, strictly decreasing and $f(b) \leq \alpha_0 \leq f(a)$ there is exactly one solution $s^*_1$ such that $f(s_1^*) = \alpha_0$
2. Let $a_n = a, b_n = b$
3. Set $I = [a_n, b_n]$
4. Check if $|I| = b_n - a_n \, < \, \epsilon$. If yes, then stop the algorithm and return $s^*_1 = \frac{1}{2}(a_n + b_n)$. If not, continue.
5. Given $I = [a_n, b_n]$ calculate the midpoint $c_n = \frac{1}{2} (a_n + b_n)$
6. Calculate $f(c_n)$. If $f(c_n) = \alpha_0$, stop the algorithm and return $s^*_1 = c_n$; 
   Else if $f(c_n) < \alpha_0$, set $a_n = a_n$ and $b_n = c_n$;
   Else, set $a_n = c_n$ and $b_n = b_n$
7. Go to point 3.

**Edit. System of quadratic equations.** One can also write a system of 4 quadratic equations of 4 unknown
parameters and try to solve it. This system, reduces to 3 quadratic equations of 3 unknown variables.

Assume you know $\text{ad}$. Let $a = \cos(\text{ad})$ and let $W
= \cos(\omega)$. Denote by $Y$ the length of segment from point
$B$ to the point of intersection of line $AE$ and line $(FP)B$
i.e. $T = CB \cap AE$. Denote by $Z$ the length of the segment
from point $A$ to the same intersection point T = $CB \cap AE$.
Let $X = s_1 - l_2$. Then, the following equations are in place:
cosine law for triangle $ABT$
$$Y^2 + Z^2 - 2aYZ - l_1^2 = 0$$

One can also write a system of 4 quadratic equations of 4 unknown
parameters and try to solve it.

Assume you know $\text{ad}$. Let $a = \cos(\text{ad})$ and let $W
= \cos(\omega)$. Denote by $Y$ the length of segment from point
$B$ to the point of intersection of line $AE$ and line $(FP)B$
i.e. $T = CB \cap AE$. Denote by $Z$ the length of the segment
from point $A$ to the same intersection point T = $CB \cap AE$.
Let $X = s_1 - l_2$. Then, the following equations are in place:
cosine law for triangle $ABT$
$$Y^2 + Z^2 - 2a\,YZ = l_1^2 $$
cosine laws for the common edge $BE$ in both triangles $BET$ and
$BE(FP)$
$$Y^2 + (Z+l_4)^2 - 2a\,Y(Z+l_4) = |BE|^2
= (X+l_2)^2 + l_7^2 - 2 l_7\, (X+l_2)W$$ cosine laws for the
common edge $CE$ in both triangles $CET$ and $CE(FP)$
$$(Y+l_2)^2 + (Z+l_4)^2 - 2a\,(Y+l_2)(Z+l_4) = |CE|^2
= X^2 + l_7^2 - 2 l_7\, (X+l_2)W$$ cosine law for triangle
$CD(FP)$
$$X^2 + l_6^2 - 2l_6\,XW = l_3^2$$
Thus, we arrive at the system of four quadratic equations and four
unknown variables
\begin{align*}
&  (X+l_2)^2 + l_7^2 - 2 l_7\,
(X+l_2)W -Y^2 - (Z+l_4)^2 + 2a\,Y(Z+l_4) = 0\\
&  X^2 + l_7^2 - 2
l_7\, (X+l_2)W -(Y+l_2)^2 - (Z+l_4)^2 + 2a\,(Y+l_2)(Z+l_4) = 0\\
& X^2 + l_6^2 - 2l_6\,XW - l_3^2 = 0\\
& Y^2 + Z^2 - 2a\,YZ - l_1^2 = 0
\end{align*}
Open parenthesis
\begin{align*}
&  X^2 + 2 l_2 \, X + l_2^2 + l_7^2 - 2 l_7\,
XW - l_2\, W - Y^2 - Z^2 - 2 l_4 \, Z - l_4^2 + 2a\,YZ + 2 a l_4\, Y = 0\\
&  X^2 + l_7^2 - 2
l_7\, XW - 2l_2 l_7 \, W - Y^2 - 2l_2\, Y - l_2^2
- Z^2 - 2l_4 \, Z - l_4^2 \\
& \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + 2a\,(YZ + l_4\,Y + l_2\, Z + l_2l_4) = 0\\
& X^2 + l_6^2 - 2l_6\,XW - l_3^2 = 0\\
& Y^2 + Z^2 - 2a\,YZ - l_1^2 = 0
\end{align*}
regroup the terms
\begin{align*}
&  X^2 - Y^2 - Z^2  + 2a\,YZ - 2 l_7\,
XW  + 2 a\, l_4\, Y - 2 l_4 \, Z + l_7^2 + 2 l_2 \, X + l_2^2  - l_2\, W  - l_4^2 = 0\\
&  X^2  - Y^2 - Z^2 + 2a\, YZ  - 2 l_7\, XW + 2a\, l_4\,Y  - 2l_4
\, Z  + l_7^2- 2l_2 l_7 \, W- 2l_2\, Y - l_2^2 - l_4^2
  \\
 & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, + 2 a l_2\, Z + 2 \, a l_2l_4 = 0\\
& X^2 + l_6^2 - 2l_6\,XW - l_3^2 = 0\\
& Y^2 + Z^2 - 2a\,YZ - l_1^2 = 0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 %&  X^2  - Y^2 - Z^2 + 2a\, YZ  - 2 l_7\, XW + 2a\, l_4\,Y  - 2l_4
%\, Z  + l_7^2 = 2l_2 l_7 \, W + 2l_2\, Y + l_2^2 + l_4^2 \\
 %& \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - 2 a l_2\, Z - 2 \, a l_2l_4 \\
& 2l_2 l_7 \, W + 2l_2\, Y + l_2^2 + l_4^2 - 2 a l_2\, Z - 2 \, a l_2l_4 + 2 l_2 \, X + l_2^2  - l_2\, W  - l_4^2 = 0\\
%%%%
&  X^2 - Y^2 - Z^2  + 2a\,YZ - 2 l_7\,
XW  + 2 a\, l_4\, Y - 2 l_4 \, Z + l_7^2 + 2 l_2 \, X + l_2^2  - l_2\, W  - l_4^2 = 0\\
& X^2 + l_6^2 - 2l_6\,XW - l_3^2 = 0\\
& Y^2 + Z^2 - 2a\,YZ - l_1^2 = 0
\end{align*}
or equivalenlty
\begin{align*}
 %&  X^2  - Y^2 - Z^2 + 2a\, YZ  - 2 l_7\, XW + 2a\, l_4\,Y  - 2l_4
%\, Z  + l_7^2 = 2l_2 l_7 \, W + 2l_2\, Y + l_2^2 + l_4^2 \\
 %& \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - 2 a l_2\, Z - 2 \, a l_2l_4 \\
&  2 l_2 \, X + 2l_2\, Y - 2 a l_2\, Z + (2l_2 l_7   - l_2)\, W +
2\,l_2^2
- 2 \, a l_2l_4 = 0\\
%%%%
&  X^2 - Y^2 - Z^2  + 2a\,YZ - 2 l_7\,
XW  + 2 a\, l_4\, Y - 2 l_4 \, Z + l_7^2 + 2 l_2 \, X + l_2^2  - l_2\, W  - l_4^2 = 0\\
& X^2 + l_6^2 - 2l_6\,XW - l_3^2 = 0\\
& Y^2 + Z^2 - 2a\,YZ - l_1^2 = 0
\end{align*}
which becomes
\begin{align*}
 %&  X^2  - Y^2 - Z^2 + 2a\, YZ  - 2 l_7\, XW + 2a\, l_4\,Y  - 2l_4
%\, Z  + l_7^2 = 2l_2 l_7 \, W + 2l_2\, Y + l_2^2 + l_4^2 \\
 %& \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, - 2 a l_2\, Z - 2 \, a l_2l_4 \\
&  2 l_2 \, X + 2l_2\, Y - 2 a l_2\, Z + (2l_2 l_7   - l_2)\, W +
2\,l_2^2
- 2 \, a l_2l_4 = 0\\
%%%%
&  X^2 - 2 l_7\,
XW  + 2 a\, l_4\, Y - 2 l_4 \, Z + l_7^2 + 2 l_2 \, X + l_2^2  - l_2\, W  - l_4^2 - l_1^2= 0\\
& X^2 + l_6^2 - 2l_6\,XW - l_3^2 = 0\\
& Y^2 + Z^2 - 2a\,YZ - l_1^2 = 0
\end{align*}
Notice, the first equation is linear in all variables $X, Y, Z, W$ so one can express $W$ as a linear combination of $X, Y, Z$ and plug it into the second and the third equations, obtaining a system of 3 quadratic equations with three unknown variables $X, Y, Z$.

Comment: I don't think this is right, since angle ad is not between l1 and l4, it's between l4 and l2.

Comment: @WhatEvil Ah, ok. I thought that was the angle. That's what it seemed to me from the picture.

Comment: @WhatEvil What about now? Is this a bit more helpful? Check for typos though, I have been a bit tired and busy today, so I haven't been very focused.

Comment: To the extent that I understand it, yes. So basically what you're saying is that there is no simple function to go from "ad" to "s1" without generating a table of values or using some recursive algorithm which "hones in on" the solution, effectively by trial and error?

Comment: @WhatEvil I can also write a system of three quadratic equations with three unknown variables, one of them $s_1$. I looked at it, but unfortunately, the solutions don't seem to come out in an obvious way. I assume that the explicit dependence of $s_1$ as a function of $\text{ad}$ is something like an elliptic function or a combination of theta functions, which are anyway some kind of analytic series, which to calculate numerically will require an approximation (like truncating the series). So finally, why bother then, if we can run a numerical method much earlier and save time.

Comment: @WhatEvil my point is that, given some angle $\text{ad}$, whatever numerical value you are going to get for $s_1$ is going to be a numerical approximation anyway. Unless you need an explicit solution, which you want to plug in some more complicated calculations (which one may find ways to circumvent anyway, depending on the problem at hand), I think a good, precise numerical method may be an excellent solution. Is your primary goal to be able to find $s_1$ for various values of $\text{ad}$?

Comment: @WhatEvil Actually, I added the quadratic system of equations, if you wish to take a look at it. The numerical method I proposed is just one possible numerical method, but I chose it because it is very convenient - you do not have to compute any derivatives for the function $f(s_1)$, you just let the computer do everything. And you can adjust the accuracy by changing $\epsilon$ as you wish.